# Breakpoint red circle glyph is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I have set a breakpoint on a line of code in my Visual Studio 2013 IDE, and in doing so I see that the red circle that usually appears on the left is missing. The line is still highlighted with the red background - that's working fine, but the red circle image is not shown.

Does anyone know if this is a setting in VS, or does it sound like something is broken?

EDIT:

Here is how a breakpoint looks in the IDE (non-running):

[image: Breakpoint Missing Glyph]

As you can see, the red circle that usually appears on the left is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Does the breakpoint still work? Try rebuilding the solution.

Comment: Yes the breakpoint still works, as in that line is hit in the IDE when I'm running the code.

Comment: Seeing the line highlighted in red is the first quirk.  Too many addins around that like to mess with these things, you have to be specific.

Comment: Hmmmm, I have been using OzCode's debugging extension recently. So that could be have changed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue was caused by a setting.

I had "Indicator Margin" disabled in the `Text Editor -> General` settings. Ticking that box fixed the problem.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Was driving me nuts!

Comment: hi! excuse me, how do you get to that "Options" sign?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I have been offline for a few days. Open the 'Tools' menu in Visual Studio, you should see the 'Options' appear in the menu that appears.

Comment: Still relevant at the end of 2022: a VS update caused the red breakpoint sphere to vanish. After 20 minutes of searching, this is the first documentation I found of the cause and solution. SO for the win!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the location of that same option in `Visual Studio Professional 2022`:

[image]

Same name and location within the option pages, just laid out in a different grouping.